# Access global object without hard-coding 'window'

Tags: javascript

I found this code in some library, which tries to avoid hard-coding `window` object:

`var global = (function () {
    return this || (1, eval)('this');
}());`

Anybody can explain the meaning of "`|| (1,eval)('this')`" part? And why to use `(1,eval)` instead of just `eval`?

Comment: (1,eval) is an indirect eval, which breaks out of a custom function with a custom _this_ when applying the code.